# API21 new DatePicker ShowWeekNumber Crash

Tags: java, android, datepicker, week-number, calendarview

I was testing my app with the new Android 5.0 (API21) but was getting an error with the CalendarView

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CalendarView does not exists for the new DatePicker
>    at android.widget.DatePickerCalendarDelegate.getCalendarView(DatePickerCalendarDelegate.java:501)
>    at android.widget.DatePicker.getCalendarView(DatePicker.java:365)
> ```

For my surprise the error was not because there is no CalendarView in the NEW API21 DatePicker, in fact, **there is no DatePicker in API21, just CalendarView.**

The error was produced because I was hidding the Week Numbers in the CalendarView

```
picker.getCalendarView().setShowWeekNumber(false);
```

This instruction throws the <kbd>UnsupportedOperationException</kbd>, be warned no more Week Numbers in the CalendarView, they just disappeared it, no explanation.

Comment: I've had users report crashes with this same error, so now I'm going to take your advice and remove the line that hides the week numbers. Thank you for posting this!

Answer (score 2):

One problem that can cause this exception is that if your DatePicker mode is `android:datePickerMode="calendar"`, DatePicker.getCalendarView would cause exception in post API 21, then in order to solve this, change the mode of your DatePicker to `android:datePickerMode="spinner"` and in java you can use from conditions to handle API greater than or equal to 21

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting confused.
your requirement is "to hide week number"
But actually there is no week Number in date picker neither in api21 nor below 21

so i suggest you skipping "picker.getCalendarView().setShowWeekNumber(false);"
line and continue with rest of code.